# How to get JSP request and response in a view Bean

Tags: java, jsp

I want to remove scriplets from JSP.
In my JSP, i have a scriplet as

```
<%response.setContentType("text/xml");%>
```

I have created a *view bean* and created a property as `HttpServletResponse response`
and added the getter/setter for this property.

When I am trying to get response in `ViewBean`, it is coming as `null`.
Any suggestions how to avoid this `NullPointerException`?

My JSP code is:

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="someBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="test" property="*" />
<jsp:getProperty name="test" property="response" />
```

ViewBean code is:

```
package test.here;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ibm.commerce.server.WcsApp;
import com.ibm.commerce.server.JSPHelper;

public class SomeBean {
    String punchOutRes = null;
    HttpServletResponse response;
    HttpServletRequest request;
    String test="Hello";
    public HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public String getPunchOutRes() {    

           response.setContentType("text/xml");
           return "testing";       
    }
    public String getTest(){    
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post the `viewBean` class and show how are you using this class in the jsp?

Comment: Use *servlet* instead of JSP. Post *relevant* code so anybody can help you out.

Comment: How will the setResponse method gets invoked in your view bean.?

Comment: Why you want to use request/response inside the *bean* or *model*? And you must have specify package.class of `class` attribute of `<jsp:useBean/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the page directive to get rid of the scriptlet above:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
```

As a rule, your bean code should *not* contain any servlet specific information.

In the servlet use:

```
request.setAttribute("test", myBean);
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In JSP use:

```
${test.foo}
```

where foo appears as

```
public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

in the bean class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when instantiating your bean you should reference the full qualified name of your java bean class (that is, **package name** plus **class name**) as follows:

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="test.here.SomeBean" />
```

In the other hand, [`<jsp:setProperty property="*" />`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/syntaxref.fm13.html) documentation says the following:

> Stores all of the values in the request object parameters (called
>   request parameters) in matching Bean properties. The property names in
>   the Bean must match the request parameters. The parameter names
>   usually come from the elements of an HTML form, and the values come
>   from the data the user enters.
>
> The values of the request parameters are always of type String. The
>   String values are converted to other data types so they can be stored
>   in Bean properties. The allowed Bean property types and their
>   conversion methods are shown in TABLE 1-1.

There is nothing in that explanation regarding the the *injection of **implicit objects*** (the request and response are implicit JSP objects, not request parameters), and **you shouldn't be using any of those objects in your bean code**.

If you just want to set the content type then use a JSP directive:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
```

But if you want to make any more complex operations then you should use a Servlet or a Filter.